# how do you add get and set for an array in c#

Tags: c#

I'm coding a func that inputs an array with different year of birth and prints out the oldest person.
I'm trying to add a validation with get and set but my syntax is wrong.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qcwgj.png)

Comment: please add your code instead of a image file

Comment: Along with the precise error, instead of "my syntax is wrong". See https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ for suggestions about writing good Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: Do you really need 2 arrays? Can't you make a class that contains a name & birth year members, then add those to a list of that class? Also, doing a bit of validation inside adding items from a console is always a good thing to think about

Comment: Where do you want to add that "validation"? Note that you already have a problem spot with that Convert.ToInt32(...) - try entering a non-number

Comment: Hey, @JonSkeet just wanted to thank you for the "C# in Depth" book. Great stuff there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### TL;DR

Properties declaration part:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    private string _fullName;
    private int _yearIn;

    public string FullName
    {
        get => _fullName;
        set
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
            {
                _fullName = value;
            }
        }

    }

    public int YearIn
    {
        get => _yearIn;
        set
        {
            if (value > 0 && value <= 2020)
            {
                _yearIn = YearIn;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And a usage:

```cs
var employees = new List<Employee>();
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Name:");
    string name = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter Year:");
    int yearIn = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    employees.Add(new Employee
    {
        FullName = name,
        YearIn = yearIn
    });
}
```

---

**Update**
You can do the same in a bit different manner though:

```cs
public class Employee
{
    private string _fullName;
    private int _yearIn;

    public bool IsNameValid { get; set; }
    public bool IsYearValid { get; set; }

    public string FullName
    {
        get => _fullName;
        set
        {
            _fullName = value;
            IsNameValid = string.IsNullOrEmpty(value);
        }

    }

    public int YearIn
    {
        get => _yearIn;
        set
        {
            _yearIn = value;
            IsYearValid = (value < 0) || (value > 2020);
        }
    }
}
```

And later:

```cs
Console.WriteLine($"Employee name is: {employees[i].IsNameValid}");
Console.WriteLine($"Employee year is: {employees[i].IsYearValid}");
```

---

**Update 2**
And the last **alternative version** is that you can use [Validation attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc3/cs/adding-validation-to-the-model):

```cs
public class Employee
{
    [Required]
    [Range(0, 2020)]
    public int YearIn { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string FullName { get; set; }
}
```

later:

```cs
var empl = new Employee{ YearIn =  yearIn, FullName = name};

var context = new ValidationContext(empl, serviceProvider: null, items: null);
var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(empl, context, results, true);
Console.WriteLine($"Is model valid: {isValid}");

if (isValid)
{
    employees.Add(new Employee
    {
        FullName = name,
        YearIn   = yearIn
    });
}
```

Comment: it's a pitty you can set the validation fields from outside the class ;) You could have autoproperties on the FullName and YearIn and get only properties for the validation stuff

Comment: @Icepickle exactly, you were ahead of me, because right now I was going to submit the version with auto properties and validation attributes. But you know it also depends on the business needs, whether it needs to be implemented with the version I've already posted or with other ways, that all depends on use cases.

Answer (score 0):

You can create wrapper classes over array and use indexer method for accessing the array item.
There in, you can put all your validation logic.

```
class IntData
    {

        public IntData(int size)
        {
            data = new int[size];
        }
        // Array of temperature values
        private int[] data;

        public int this[int index]
        {
            get
            {
                return data[index];
            }

            set
            {
                // Do your validation here
                if (value < 5000) 
                {
                    data[index] = value;
                }
            }
        }
    }


      static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IntData year = new IntData(3);
            year[0] = 2000;
            year[1] = 6000; // This value won't set because of validation
            year[2] = 4000;

            Console.Read();
        }
```

Comment: This is similar to validation when setting properties. We can throw exception when user try to set some invalid value and not allow the user to enter that value.